# Autofilling my form in Access with the use of a Combo Box

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm having a problem when I want to autofill my form in Microsoft Access. The idea is that I use a combo box to select a name. Then the onChange code of my Combobox automaticlly inserts all the other data in the proper field. I use this code on the Combo Box.

```
Private Sub cmbName_Change()
Me.tbPersonalNumber = Me.cmbName.Column(0)
Me.tbEmailadress = Me.cmbName.Column(2)
Me.tbBirthday = Me.cmbName.Column(3)
End Sub
```

This methode works fine for the personalnumber and the emailadress. But it doesn't work for the birthday date, it returns a null value but when I check my table there is is a date in the proper field.

Am I missing something? I tried everything but it wont work.
I was thinking that the problem is related to the birthday column being the last in the table. Or having the date type.

Thank you in advance for your time and efford!

Edit; The .Column(1) is missing because this is the name that is already inserted with the ComboBox.

Comment: Does the birthday date show up in the combobox (when dropped down)? If its column width is 0, enlarge it while debugging. -- In my opinion, the _AfterUpdate event is better for this than _Change, but if the rest works, that is probably not the problem.

Comment: @Andre The birthday date does not show up in the combobox when dropped down. However I did find out that the PersonalNumber does. Maybe this is part of the problem? This is the SQL that the combo box has "SELECT Personel.PersonalNumber, Personel.Name, Personel.Emailadress, Personel.Birthday FROM Personel ORDER BY Personel.Name; "

Comment: have you check the column count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some confusion caused by the wording of the question, I'll try to state back how I've interpreted and if I have it right it may lead you to an answer.

You have combo box called `cmdName` that is pre-populated with data from a table. The content of the combo box could look as below (you may have set column widths to zero to hide the data)

```
0001|Gary Evans|gary@email.com|01/Jan/1970
0002|J Rommers |JR@email.com  |02/Jan/1970
```

When the user selects `J Rommers` `Me.tbPersonalNumber` is populated with `Me.cmbName.Column(0)` (0002) and `Me.tbEmailadress` is populated with `Me.cmbName.Column(2)` (JR@email.com) but `Me.tbBirthday` is not being populated with `Me.cmbName.Column(3)` (02/Jan/1970).

Assuming `Me.tbBirthday` is a text box with no code that might clear it out, I suspect the issue is within the combo box. Not being sure how your combo box is set up, I would suggets the following checks:-

- In the combo box properties, does the `Column Count` equal 4?
- In debug, with a breakpoint on `Me.tbBirthday = Me.cmbName.Column(3)`, does it show you the date you are after?

  - If it is not there does the query that populates the combo box have it in?

---

Edit based on comments to help further: -

- Change the query to `SELECT Personel.PersonalNumber, Personel.Emailadress, Personel.Birthday, Personel.Name FROM Personel ORDER BY Personel.Name;` this puts all the fields you want hidden at the front.
- Change the column widths property of `cmbName` to `0,0,0`, this first the ones you want hidden and leave the last one to fill the width of the combo box.
- Ensure the column count property is still 4 as per the answer
- Change your code as per below and [Gustav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3527297/gustav)'s answer

Replacement code:-

```
Me.tbPersonalNumber = Me.cmbName.Column(0)
Me.tbEmailadress = Me.cmbName.Column(1)
Me.tbBirthday = DateValue(Me.cmbName.Column(2))
```

This accounts for the fields moving in the query and ensure the date shows as a date like you wanted.

Comment: This in combination with the awnser of @Gustav above works! Thank your very much!

Comment: I've added more information to get the format you wanted as well.

Answer (score 1):

Comboboxes (and Listboxes) always return a string, so convert that to a Date value:

```
Me!tbBirthday.Value = DateValue(Me!cmbName.Column(3))
```